# count user per day who played in a game from the DB

Tags: sql

I have a database for a small game with a table answers:
each user can play and answer max 2 times a day,
The table answer is structurized like this:

`UID |  ANSWER  |  DATE`

I would like to do a query to get how many user played at least one time per day.
I did something like this but this is not working.

```
SELECT Day(date) as n, 
       Dayname(date) as m, 
       uid,             
       COUNT(uid) as c 
FROM answers
WHERE Year(date) = '2012' 
GROUP BY uid HAVING count( * ) <=2 //COUNT user who played at least 2 times per day
GROUP BY n //group by day
ORDER BY n
```

And I would like to have a result like this:

`Friday | 9-5-2012 | 1254`

`Saturday | 10-5-2012  |  1427`
...

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Wouldn't "..who played at least 1 time per day" already be that the uid has an entry at all for that day? Or did you in fact mean "who played more than once per day"?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two `group by` clauses, use a single one that groups on day:

```
select  day(date) as d
,       month(date) as m
,       count(distinct uid) as c 
from    answers
where   year(date) = '2012' 
group by 
        day(date)
,       month(date)
having  count(*) > 1
```

Comment: don't `group by uid` if that's what you want to count, and question originally asks for 'at least one time per day', not 'at least 2'.

Comment: Thx guys it works like a charm now! My knowledge of SQL is quite limitated...
Thx for your help!